# Exclude document type from search results?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to exclude all .pdf documnets from being searchable, in a particular site and all its subsites. Note, the starting site is NOT a top-level site collection.

Can this be done?

I'm using SharePoint Online?

Thanks,

JT

Comment: Do you mean how many questions I mark as answered? I will see what I can do. I haven't been marking things as answered, as generally it seems there's always scope for more answers. And I wouldn't want to kill the question. I guess I'm doing it wrong!

Comment: I'll review my older questions, and bear it in mind for new ones. Where do you see this percentage? I can't see yours?

Comment: It's visible when someone asks a question. Answering your question now.

Comment: You can see it right beneath your name and avatar at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Got it! I'm up 19% already! Thanks guys will make more of an effort with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this:

1) Exclude the file extension using scopes in central admin and tell the search results page to use this scope

2) Remove the ifilter if you want it removed completely

3) Filter with an xslt transformation on the search results page

I would if it was the whole farm I would go for option 2, if it is for a single collection then option one, if it is for a small site then option 3.

Comment: Thanks Hugh. It's SharePoint Online so I don't have access to Central Admin for 1). I'll investigate the other two. Don't suppose you know if they apply to SharePoint Online?

Comment: You can do the xslt transformation only.